# Vertically Centering an Image

Tags: support, design, markdown, images

We can embed images through HTML tags. For example, if I was bitterly writing equations through http://www.google.com instead of using LaTeX like I can on http://math.stackexchange.com, I could do this: [image: x=\frac{d-c}{a-b}]

With the HTML: `<img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=x%3D%5Cfrac%7Bd-c%7D%7Ba-b%7D" alt="x=\frac{d-c}{a-b}">`

But as you can see that's top aligned, which is not always desirable. So I'd like to use the [`align="middle"`](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/att_img_align.asp) attribute. But I get this:

With the HTML: `<img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=x%3D%5Cfrac%7Bd-c%7D%7Ba-b%7D" alt="x=\frac{d-c}{a-b}" align="middle">`

Is there something I'm doing wrong or do we just not support that markup? Is there a Markdown alternative available to me?

Comment: this is a very specific case for having an image of a formula aligned when it's inline. couldn't you just present the image on a new line of it's own? or do you have any other _justification_ for this request?

Comment: Oh, yes, I suppose it is. I saw the question as what I wanted to see. It would still look very messy to have this formula displayed on the same line as the text, regardless of the vertical alignment. It should be on a separate line, *horizontally* centered, which we unfortunately do not support, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `align="middle"` attribute isn't [whitelisted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites) for use here. To be safe, markdown just removes all HTML that contains anything that isn't whitelisted.

Basically, `align="middle"` isn't supported, so the element isn't rendered. There is no "pure markdown" alternative.